# Drawing a circular arc between two rays

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two rays drawn with a common endpoint at A.  I mark a point 3/7 of the way from A to the end of one of the rays, and label it `P`.  I want to draw a circular arc centered at A through P between the rays.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%Three points are labeled in the Cartesian plane.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (75:3);
\coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(5,0)$);

%Two rays are drawn
\draw[name path=path_AB, -latex] (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=path_AC, -latex] (A) -- (C);

%The four vertices are labeled.
\node at ($(A)! -2.5mm! (C)$){$A$};
\node at ($(B)! -2.5mm! (A)$){$k$};
\node at ($(C)! -2.5mm! (A)$){$\ell$};

%The circular arc centered at A starts at P.
\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!3/7!(B)$);
\draw[fill] (B') circle (1.5pt);


%An arc between the rays starting at P.

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated

Since you already defined `P`, you can calculate the length that goes from `A` to it and then use the updated version of the command you see in the old solution:

```
%An arc between the rays starting at P.
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\radius}{(3/7)*3cm}
\draw (P) arc (80:30:\radius) node[pos=0,left] {$P$};
```

[image: figure 1]

### Old solution

If you don't have a point already, as in your case, you can just add this to your code:

```
\draw ++(75:1) arc (75:27:1) node[pos=0,left] {$P$};
```

which does:

- Start from `(0,0)` (the A coordinate) and move `1` in the direction of the `75` angle
- From there, draw an arc that goes from the angle `75` to the angle `27`.`1` is the radius.
- Finally, add a node `P` at the start of the arc, on the left.

[image: figure 2]

### Some explanations

> Is the part ++(75:1) compiled the same as (0,0) ++(75:1)?

Yes, it's the same thing.

> Why do you have 27 in (75:27:1)?

`75` is the starting angle, while `27` is the end angle. These angles are not the angle at which the path exits or enters, here's an image to show what I mean:

[image: figure 3]

Comment: The point P is already given. The desired arc has to pass through P. You answer locates another point P in a position that differs from the actual position of the already existing P.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ops. Didn't see that. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @Alenanno   I am not familiar with `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` command.  Why can't you have `\draw (P) arc (80:30:(3/7)*3cm)`?

Comment: @Alenanno  Nice to hear from you again.

Comment: @Alenanno  I think that you missed my previous comment.  "I am not familiar with \pgfmathsetlengthmacro command. Why can't you have \draw (P) arc (80:30:(3/7)*3cm)?"

Comment: @user74973 Actually you can, but you need to write it like `arc (80:30:{(3/7)*3cm})`, with curly braces.

Comment: @user74973 The `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` is useful in case you want to reuse the same value, then you just type `\radius` or whatever name you decide.

Comment: @Alenanno  I would like to discuss your first code.  Recall that I have `\coordinate (B) at (75:3);` and `\coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(5,0)$);`. You said that if I had not already specified the point `P` and all that I wanted was an arc centered at `A` between the rays, I could issue `\draw ++(75:1) arc (75:27:1)`.  Is the part `++(75:1)` compiled the same as `(0,0) ++(75:1)`?  Why do you have `27` in `(75:27:1)`?  Couldn't I adapt this command, replacing `27` with something like `{atan((3*cos(75) + 5)/(3*sin(75)))}`?

Comment: @user74973 I'm unable to reply properly because I'm not using my computer right now. I'll update the answer tomorrow (it's night here) to address your doubts.

Comment: @user74973 See updated answer.

Comment: @Alenanno  Sorry for the delay.  I just "got on" my computer.  (Odd idiom.)  There is a misunderstanding.  I understand the syntax for drawing an arc.  With `\coordinate (B) at (75:3);` and `\coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(5,0)$);` couldn't I draw an arc, centered at the origin, from `B` to the ray containing `C` with a command like `\draw ++(75:1) arc (75:{atan((3*cos(75) + 5)/(3*sin(75)))}:1)`?

Comment: @user74973 Not sure what you mean, but have you tried? :D

Comment: @Alenanno  Yes, I compiled the code `\draw ++(75:3) arc (75:{atan((3*cos(75) + 5)/(3*sin(75)))}:3);`.  I did not get an arc of a circle.

Comment: @user74973 Me neither, but I don't really know that kind of code. I mean, it's beyond my current knowledge.

Comment: The point (or vector, in the lingo of programming) `(3*cos(75) + 5,  3*sin(75))` is a point (or vector) that is a horizontal shift of the point `(75:3)`.  The angle of the line through the origin and this shifted point, `Q`, is `atan((3*cos(75) + 5) / (3*sin(75)))`.  So, using the arc command to draw an arc of a circle, centered at the origin, from `P` to the line through the origin and `Q`, I think that something like `\draw ++(75:1) arc (75:{atan((3*cos(75) + 5)/(3*sin(75)))}:1)` should work.

Comment: @Alenanno  Actually, `TikZ` does compile the code as expected.  The points `P` and `Q` are close enough that an arc through them seems to be a line segment.  I drew a line segment between them and magnified the image six times to see that the line segment and arc were drawn differently.  It is useful to be able to use the `calc` package to compute angles of such awkward expressions.

Answer (score 11):

Two options.

1. Clipping a circle using the rays:

   ```
   \begin{scope}
   \clip (B) -- (A) -- (C);
   \path[draw] 
     let
     \p1=( $ (A) - (P) $ )
     in
     (A) circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
   \end{scope}
   ```
2. using the `angles` library:

   ```
   \path[draw] 
     let
     \p1=( $ (A) - (P) $ )
     in
     pic[draw,angle radius={veclen(\x1,\y1)}] {angle = C--A--B};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

In both cases, the `calc` library was used to calculate the radius.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%Three points are labeled in the Cartesian plane.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (75:3);
\coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(5,0)$);

%Two rays are drawn
\draw[name path=path_AB, -latex] (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=path_AC, -latex] (A) -- (C);

%The four vertices are labeled.
\node at ($(A)! -2.5mm! (C)$){$A$};
\node at ($(B)! -2.5mm! (A)$){$k$};
\node at ($(C)! -2.5mm! (A)$){$\ell$};

%The circular arc centered at A starts at P.
\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!3/7!(B)$);
%\draw[fill] (B') circle (1.5pt);

\node[left] at (P) {$P$};

\begin{scope}
\clip (B) -- (A) -- (C);
\path[draw] 
  let
  \p1=( $ (A) - (P) $ )
  in
  (A) circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\end{scope}

\path[draw] 
  let
  \p1=( $ (A) - (P) $ )
  in
  pic[draw,angle radius={veclen(\x1,\y1)}] {angle = C--A--B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is the display that I wanted.  I am not familiar with `let`.  I will refer to the manual.  Please explain `{veclen(\x1,\y1)}`.

Comment: @user74973  `veclen(a,b)` is a PGF math function which calculates `\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}`; in this case, I used it to calculate the length of the segment from "A" to "P", since `\x1` and `\y1` are the `x` and `y` coordinates, respectively, of the point `A-P` .

Comment: I just looked in `http://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf` for a discussion of `let`.  I didn't see it.  May you suggest a web site for it?

Comment: @user74973 Always refer to CTAN for up-to-date documentation: [`PGF manual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), Section **14.15 The Let Operation**.

Comment: Option 1b: Clipping and then `\node[draw] at (A) [circle through=(P)]{};` (The math is the same, just the interface is different.) Needs the `through` library, though.